# Xslt : Ignoring elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I retrieve from database xml strings :

either :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Parameters>
  <StringParameter name="field">TNA</StringParameter>
  <DateParameter name="date">2011-12-14T00:00:00</DateParameter>
</Parameters>
```

either :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ArrayOfPrimitiveParameter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PrimitiveParameter>
    <Name>field</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">TNA</Value>
  </PrimitiveParameter>
  <PrimitiveParameter>
    <Name>date</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-12-14T00:00:00</Value>
  </PrimitiveParameter>
</ArrayOfPrimitiveParameter>
```

I want to transform the output **only in the second case**. But my xslt stylesheet transform all cases (1 and 2). Today I have made workaround using SQL Where filter but I want to know how to do this with XSL.

Here is my XsltStyleSheet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsd xsi" 
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes"  />
  <xsl:template match="ArrayOfPrimitiveParameter" >

    <Parameters>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Parameters>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PrimitiveParameter">

    <!-- String -->
    <xsl:if test="Value/@xsi:type='xsd:string'">
     <xsl:element name="StringParameter">
       <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:if test="Key">
          <xsl:attribute name="DomainKey">
            <xsl:value-of select="Key" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- DateTime -->
    <xsl:if test="Value/@xsi:type='xsd:dateTime'">
      <xsl:element name="DateParameter">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- Boolean -->
    <xsl:if test="Value/@xsi:type='xsd:boolean'">
      <xsl:element name="BoolParameter">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- Double -->
    <xsl:if test="Value/@xsi:type='xsd:double'">
      <xsl:element name="BoolParameter">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Regards,

Florian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend basing your stylesheet on the identity template. This outputs all input unchanged - except the elements that you explicitly write templates for.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsd xsi" 
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes"  />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ArrayOfPrimitiveParameter">
    <Parameters>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Parameters>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PrimitiveParameter">
    <xsl:variable name="elemName">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Value/@xsi:type" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Name | Key" />
      <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@xsi:type">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=". = 'xsd:string'">StringParameter</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test=". = 'xsd:dateTime'">DateParameter</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test=". = 'xsd:boolean'">BoolParameter</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test=". = 'xsd:double'">DoubleParameter</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>UnknownParameter</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Key">
    <xsl:attribute name="DomainKey">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I rewrote your approach, making it more generic. See if you like the change or not.

Comment: Did you not also intend to suppress the `Parameters` element, which I believe OP said he did not want transformed?

Comment: He said: *"I want to transform the output only in the second case"*, which implies that he wants to keep the first case unchanged.

Comment: Hmm, that's certainly a valid interpretation.  I was thinking, especially given the title mentioning "ignoring," that the first case should be ignored completely not copied over completely.  @Florian?

Comment: In fact, it's cleaner !

Comment: @Florian In XSLT you cannot ignore elements. All elements in the input are always handled in some way - either by the [built-in default templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) or by ones that you write yourself. "Not handling" elements in this context maps to "copying them as they are" - which is exactly what the identity template does.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly ignore an element in the input document by matching and doing nothing with it:

```
  <xsl:template match="Parameters"/>
```

This will match and suppress `Parameters`, overriding any more general matching such as would be used to copy elements over to the output by default.

Note that it will *not* override more specific matching patterns:

```
  <xsl:template match="Parameters[StringParameter/@name = 'field']">
  ...
  </xsl:template>
```